# Position 3 or more divs centrally within a single container div

Tags: css

I cant seem to find a definitive answer to this. I have three or more div's each 120px wide within a div of 100% width;
The amount of divs in the div is variable, but I want them to appear in the centre of the containing div and spread outwards from the middle the more that are added.
I guess I could probably just wrap them in a  tag, but I would rather a CSS way of doing it.
Can anyone provide a nice mechanism for doing this at all please?

Comment: It would be good if you could put the code on http://jsfiddle.net/ as I'm having difficulty visualising it. I don't think I could solve this just with css.

Comment: Are you looking for something like float:center? neither left nor right? You may be interested in this article: http://www.pmob.co.uk/pob/centred-float.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking for too much for pure CSS. [Here is what I came up with](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/2Z8an/). But it's not what you want. The #innerwrap would need a variable width (auto would be best) but that would break the rules for centering its contents. So I don't think it's possible without some jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#container{
  border:1px solid blue;
  margin:0;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:center;
}
#container div{
  display:inline;

    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: With thanks to http://csswizardry.com/2011/01/create-a-centred-horizontal-navigation/ (again!) Although you can't give the divs a 120px fixed width just like that, due to the display inline, you'd have to create width width padding, or have another element inside the div with a width of 120px.

Answer (score 0):

What about: http://jsfiddle.net/jennyfofenny/eSR89/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:inline-block for centered divs.